# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [889, 418]

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am making a logistic regression model and have separate training and testing dataset file. All my code works perfect on fitting and prediction of model, but when I apply (Classification_report(y, prediction))
then it shows (Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [889, 418]) error. My testing dataset have only 418 rows while training has 889 rows.
Please tell me how can I fix this??

Comment: Could you include your code here (in triple backticks `\`\`\`py \`\`\``) so people can see what's happening please?

Comment: It sounds like the features X + labels Y are getting mixed up with the training + testing sets

Answer (score 0):

When the error is outputting "inconsistent number of samples", it means that your y and prediction variables have a different first dimension. In your case, one of the variables have their first dimension as 889 and the second variable has the first dimension as 418.

As for fixing this, this could be solved with a simple np.reshape(), however if that doesn't work you may have to look at your code again to find out where you might have messed up in the predictions and/or in the y variable